# Jenkins postbuild groovy plugin - Append text to Build summary with line breaks

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I would like to append notes entered for a build using parametrized build to be appended to the build summary page with the line breaks entered. I added the following code in the groovy postbuild plugin:

```
manager.addInfoBadge("Notes added")
manager.createSummary("notepad.png").appendText("${manager.build.buildVariables.get('notes_for_build')}", false, false, false, "black")
```

But, the text seems to be wrapped into one line as shown below:

[image]

Could anyone please let me know how to retain the line breaks?

Comment: Could you wrap it in a `<pre>` tag?

Comment: Tim: Perfect! Could you please post this as an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try wrapping your message in a `<pre>...</pre>` tag, so linebreaks get rendered by the browser :-)

Comment: I have the <pre> tag but it is failing with latest Jenkins and all the lines are wrapped

Answer (score 0):

I found success by adding `<br>` to every `\n`. (It being HTML in that context.)